# How can I fetch Distinct Value using JOIN in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1

```
|id | name |
|-----------
|1  | Test |
|2  | Hello|
|3  | Hii  |
------------
```

Table 2

```
------------------------------------
|id | name | related_id | Comments |
|-----------------------------------
|1  | Test |     1      |  Example |
|2  | Hello|     2      | Example2 |
|3  | Hello|     2      | Example3 |
|4  | Hello|     2      | Example3 |
------------------------------------
```

So, I want to output is like following :

```
|id | name | Comments  |
|-----------------------
|1  | Test | Example   |
|2  | Hello| Example3  |
|3  | Hii  |      -    |
------------------------
```

I want all records from Table 1 and from table 2 only Distict record needed. 
So tell me how can I use JOIN query.

Comment: If table1.id relates to table2.related_id, then there are three items in table2 for related_id = 2 ("Example2", "Example3", and "Example3").  While the two "Example3" values could be DISTINCT'ed away (mostly as @Manmohan describes), you'd still have a value of "Example2" that would be output.

Answer (score 1):

After the `WHERE` and before `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` (if any), there is a `GROUP BY` clause, where you list the columns you want to be distinct (that's a very informal way to explain it).

In your case, you should `GROUP BY name`.

I won't go into more detail. Now that you know all the "keywords", you are able to Google effectively which you should do to gain a solid understanding of how `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY` work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example query that returns the specified resultset,

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , MAX(m.comments) AS comments
  FROM Table1 t
  LEFT
  JOIN Table2 m
    ON m.related_id = t.id
 GROUP
    BY t.id
     , t.name
```

NOTES:
The `GROUP BY` clause effectively collapses rows into a set of rows that have distinct values for the `id` and `name` columns.

The "join" operation returns rows from Table1, along with matching rows from Table2. In this example, and row in Table2 that has a `related_id` value equal to an `id` value in Table1 will be returned.

Because we also want to return rows from Table1 that do *not* have a matching row in Table2, we need an "outer" join operation. The addition of the `LEFT` keyword achieves that for us. (The driving table is on the "left" side of the join keyword.)

This is just an example; there are likely other requirements that the sample data doesn't sufficiently illustrate, and which won't be satisfied with this query.

Because there can be multiple rows from Table2 returned for each row from Table1, we need a way to distinguish which of the "comments" values should be returned. Based on the example data, the MAX() aggregate function will achieve the specified result.

Answer (score 0):

**BOTH** queries shown below produce this result:

```
| ID |  NAME | RELATED_ID | COMMENTS |
|----|-------|------------|----------|
|  1 |  Test |          1 |  Example |
|  2 | Hello |          2 | Example3 | <<<< Note this is "the last comment" for id 2
|  3 |   Hii |     (null) |   (null) |
```

This expected result can be achieved with `GROUP BY`and using MAX(T2.comments) to get the "last comment"

```
SELECT
      T1.id , T1.name , T2.related_id , MAX(T2.comments) as comments
FROM Table1 T1
      LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.related_id
GROUP BY
     T1.id , T1.name , T2.related_id 
;
```

The requirement may also be achieved using `NOT EXISTS` which also choose the "last comment" as follows:

```
SELECT
      T1.id , T1.name , T2.related_id , T2.comments
FROM Table1 T1
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        t22.*
                  FROM table2 t22
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                              SELECT NULL
                              FROM table2 t23
                              WHERE t22.related_id = t23.related_id
                                    AND t23.id > t22.id
                        )
            ) T2 ON T1.id = T2.related_id
;
```

The advantage of this approach is that a whole record from Table2 is chosen (in this case the one with the highest ID).

Both the queries above meet the expected result, the technique to choose depends on if you need more information from T2 than MAX(comments) would provide.

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39a1e/2)</kbd>

---

This question really has nothing to do with `DISTINCT`, the requirement is to choose a just one related record from Table2 for each record in Table1. It also requires an `OUTER JOIN` because not all records in Table1 are represented in Table2.

`SELECT DISTINCT` is a `row operator`.

It only makes one decision, and that decision is to compare the **entire row** to all other rows, and if the row is unique it survives, otherwise it is excluded.

So `SELECT DISTINCT` CANNOT work on just one part of the row or on just one column, and it does not solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let I explain you in detail.

In relative table, there are ID 2 repeats for 5 time. So When I will use GROUP BY so it will show 1 record instead of all. right? But I exactly want that last record of  repeated ID 2. Because it shows first record by default. So how can I get last record of repeated ID 2?

Comment: how can I get last record of repeated ID 2? **please read the answer I provided** there are 2 methods, if you have further questions do NOT add an answer, use "add a comment" below the answer please. also look at this url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39a1e/2

Answer (score -1):

use `distinct` keyword

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id, T1.name, T2.related_id, T2.comments 
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
WHERE T1.id=T2.id;
```

This is a join Query

Comment: I think they meant that table1.id would relate to table2.related_id.  If you straight join, you lose row 3 ("Hii"), which they wanted in the output.

Comment: Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead, and move the join predicates from the WHERE clause to an ON clause.  Also, example resultset from OP suggests that this should be an "outer" join, so that rows from Table1 are returned when there is no matching row from Table2. The DISTINCT keyword won't cause the rows to be "collapsed", as is shown in the OP example resultset.  (This may qualify as an answer, but it does *not* address the question asked by OP; the suggestion to "use the DISTINCT keyword" misses the mark by a large margin.)